# 3D Scanner Depth Distortion

Tags: c++, opencv, 3d, camera-calibration, projector

I am trying to build structured light scanner using OpenCV Structured Light API. I am using stereo camera and making calibration them between camera pair.

Stereo camera error is around 0.26 

Individual camera error is also around 0.22

But at the end of decoding of gray code pattern I am getting strange depth distortion on image (link is below). Result should be flat surface but there seems very curvy surface.
What makes such an error?

https://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/dc/da9/tutorial_decode_graycode_pattern.html

Depth distortion error image

https://ibb.co/fp8jU6

https://ibb.co/f16op6

Comment: undistort the sensors with known objects.

Comment: there is already a part about undistort and remapping. 
initUndistortRectifyMap( cam1intrinsics, cam1distCoeffs, R1, P1, imagesSize, CV_32FC1, map1x, map1y ); 
remap( captured_pattern[1][i], captured_pattern[1][i], map1x, map1y, INTER_NEAREST, BORDER_CONSTANT, Scalar() ); <br/> But it seems not working well or possibly I have too much problem about calibration

Comment: if you remove that part, are the results better or worse?

Comment: i think there is not so much difference with/without remap
https://ibb.co/c3yw96
without remap
https://ibb.co/m92pU6
with remap is little bit better on object surface

Comment: Just to double check, you are certain you have not moved the hardware between the time of calibration and time of 3D capture? Also are you certain the focus of the cameras are not set to automatic?

Comment: yes I am sure about that

Comment: What is the baseline of your cameras (approximately in mm) and what is the distance of your object to the cameras (approximately in mm)? I ask because if the distance is too far relative to baseline it is impossible to get accurate depthmaps.

Comment: distance between cameras is around 125mm and angle is 28 degree. distance to scanning object 240mm

Answer (score 0):

When I compared with the other open source projects, there seems a mistake with remapping.

Remap functions should used like below

```
remap( captured_pattern[0][i], captured_pattern[0][i], map1x, map1y, INTER_NEAREST, BORDER_CONSTANT, Scalar() );
remap( captured_pattern[1][i], captured_pattern[1][i], map2x, map2y, INTER_NEAREST, BORDER_CONSTANT, Scalar() );
```